# Autocorrelation function in Ising model Python

Tags: python, physics, montecarlo, autocorrelation

I am trying to use Python to plot the graph of autocorrelation function of metropolis algorithm by following the methodology of this [lecture note](https://physics.bu.edu/py502/lect5/mc.pdf). Autocorrelation function in this lecture note are defined as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KmnB.png) and the graph should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zre4.png) with small standard deviation. Here is my code:

```
def computeAutocorrelation(Q_list,taunum,knum):
    A_list_tau = []
    A_std_tau = []
    
    for tau in range(taunum):
      
        A_list_k = [(Q_list[k]*Q_list[k+tau]- np.mean(Q_list[:knum-tau])**2)/variance(Q_list[:knum-tau]) for k in range(knum-tau)]

        A_list_tau.append(np.mean(A_list_k))
        A_std_tau.append(np.std(A_list_k))
        
        if A_list_tau[-1] <=0.01:
            A_list_tau.extend([np.nan]*(taunum-len(A_list_tau)))
            A_std1_tau.extend([np.nan]*(taunum-len(A_std_tau)))
            break

    return A_list_tau, A_std1_tau
```

However when I plot this function, my graph look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnSUX.png) with large standard deviation.

Is there any mistake(s) I made in calculating autocorrelation function or standard deviation?